# Why does my chart plot extra x-axis width?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd Charts in my project to plot timeseries data. My data has datapoints only till 18:30 pm but antd Line Chart plots extra x-axis width which makes it look like the data is missing.

This is my config:

```
 const config = {
    width: window.innerWidth - 100,
    data: res,
    xField: 'time',
    yField: 'value',
    seriesField: 'key',
    yAxis: {
      title: { position: 'center', text: labelText, autoRotate: true },
      grid: {
        line: {
          style: {
            stroke: '#ddd',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'time',
      mask: 'HH:mm Z',
      label: {
        formatter: (value) => {
          if (timezone === 'utc') {
            return moment(value, 'HH:mm ZZ').utc().format('HH:mm Z');
          }
          return moment(value, 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm Z');
        },
      },
      grid: {
        line: {
          style: {
            stroke: '#ddd',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      customItems: (originalItems) => {
        return originalItems.sort(function (a, b) {
          return b.value - a.value;
        });
      },
    },
  };
```

How do I remove the extra x-axis part between 18:30 and 18:47

[image: Antd chart with extra x-axis]

Comment: removing the `type: 'time'` field from the xAxis property seems to work for me. There seems to be some bug or intended behaviour in antd library